# using @font-face with flying saucer issue

Tags: java, pdf, itext, font-face, flying-saucer

I'm trying to convert an html to pdf using flying saucer pdf library, but I have an issue with the font I should have. It seems that the font imported is not recognized.

Below my html code:

```
<html>     
<head>     
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <title>My card - v_prenom v_nom</title>  
    <style>
        p {
            margin: 0;
            font-family:'Poppins',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
        }
    </style> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900%26display=swap" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>     
<body>
...

    <td style="text-align:center;">             
        <p style="font-size:10px">   <strong>Card<br/>Test</strong></p>
                    </td>    

...
</body>
...
```

And my java code:

```
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFolder);
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer(); 
        
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(path+data_in+"template.html");
        
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
        
        StringBuilder content=new StringBuilder(1024);
        
        String s;
        
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
            
            content.append(s);
       } 

       String html_string = content.toString();

       renderer.setDocumentFromString(html_string);

       renderer.layout(); 
       
       renderer.createPDF(outputStream);  
        
       outputStream.close();
```

The result pdf is generated but not using the font that I wanted, any idea of where the problem can come ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flying-saucer doesn't support the Web Open Font Format (WOFF) fonts, which is used by google fonts.

If you want to use Poppins, you must download the `ttf` file and include it in the java code:

```java
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("font/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("so.pdf"));
renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(out);
out.close();
```